# A word for 'a series of events'

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I'm trying to find a word to describe a series of events.  For example, the revolution in Lybia consists of a series of chronological events.  I want to say 'development', but that seems to refer more to a single event.

Comment: The answer is simply **"events."**  Just for the record, in your sentence, it's "chronological series of events" or better simply "series of events." series/chronological is somewhat tautological in any combination.  "series of chronological events" is horribly tautological.

Comment: I believe the point they're making is that one event causes the next one. A sets off B sets off C. Instead of A and B having their own origins, but combining to set off C. For example, boy wants beer -> goes to bar -> meets girl, versus, boy goes to bar + girl goes to bar -> boy + girl meet.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few words:

> Train
>   String
>   Proceedings

If you don't mind several words, how about:

> Train of events
>   Succession of events.

Answer (score 2):

The Revolution in Libya was comprised of a succession of several events.

Answer (score 2):

Consider,

***chain*** *of events*

> A series of occurrences [WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/chain%20of%20events)

***cascade*** *of events*

> cascade: A large number of things that happen in a series [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cascade)

***concatenation*** *of events*

> concatenation: A series of interconnected events, concepts, etc. [FOD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/concatenation)

***consecution*** *of events*

> consecution: a sequence or succession [FOD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/consecution)

Comment: +1 for "chain" (which I borrowed to use in my answer)

Answer (score 2):

Your goal seems to be to replace all three words in “series of events” with one word, but I don’t see one.  However, if you’re willing to consider two words that would cover both “series” and “events,” I’d propose “[chain reaction](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/chain+reaction)”:

> chain reaction n. 1. A series of events in which each induces or
>   influences the next.
>
> chain reaction n  3. a series of rapidly occurring events, each of
>   which precipitates the next.
>
> chain′ reac`tion n. 2. a series of events in which each event is the
>   result of the one preceding and the cause of the one following.
>   [1925–30]

(from ‘American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language,’ ‘Collins English Dictionary,’ and ‘Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary,’ respectively, all via ‘The Free Dictionary by Farlex’)

The revolution in Lybia [,as most revolutions are,] was a chain reaction.

Answer (score 1):

How about :

> "Revolution in Lybia coalesced due to
>   combination of events."

or

> "Revolution in Lybia developed due to combination
>   of events."

Events being chronological is already inferred as no one has invented a time machine yet ( as we know of).
Also there is a stronger condition has been imposed on the series of events, namely the specific combination ( be it their chronlogical order or type-of-event wise ).

Answer (score 0):

to be worthy of a 6th answer, please consider **skein**

> a succession or series of similar or interrelated things: a skein of
>   tennis victories.  [dictionary.com][1]
>
> [1]: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/skein

As in:

> The revolution in Lybia was a tangled **skein** of events.